# Firebase Query and angularJS

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Regarding the data below, how I get the record where phoneNo is 222 using angularfire.

```
    var db = new Firebase("myFB/names");
    $scope.synchArr = $firebaseArray(db);

 names{
     K7VQBTELD4FQE1HL1U{
        name: "a",
        phoneNo: 111
      }

     K7WJGBTELD4FQ1EHL1U{
         name: "b",
        phoneNo: 222
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get that record with:

```
var name = db.orderByChild('phoneNo').equalTo(222);
$scope.name = $firebaseObject(name);
```

Since AngularFire is built on top of the [Firebase JavaScript SDK](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries), you can use all the features that are available in there.

Comment: Thank you but I want to retrieve the entire object. I try this:  var db = new Firebase("myFB/names"); db.orderByChild('phoneNo').equalTo(222).on("value", function(snapshot) {
        console.log("here: " + snapshot.val());
      }); I get this: here: [object Object]